# A way to find the average of multiple rows of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Not quite sure how to word the question, but pretty much I have a dataframe with some values pertaining to California counties. Looks something like:

| County | Score | Score Pctl | Ozone | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fresno | 94 | 100 | 0.065 | ... |
| San Francisco | 91 | 99 | 0.067 | ... |
| San Bernardino | 89 | 97 | 0.055 | ... |
| Fresno | 87 | 96 | 0.067 | ... |
| San Diego | 86 | 95 | 0.053 | ... |
| Fresno | 86 | 95 | 0.064 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

The dataframe has many more columns and rows, with each county having up to ~100 different rows pertaining to their data. I want to make a new dataframe composed of the average amongst all the counties' rows, so I'll have a dataframe of ~50 rows instead of ~8000. How would I go about finding the average values for the rows?

Comment: `df.groupby('County', as_index=False).mean()` ?is that what you searching for ?

Comment: Thank you that's precisely what I was looking for. Very new to all this, so I wasn't aware of `.groupby`! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As simple as `groupy` + `mean`...

```
>>> df.groupby('County', as_index=False).mean()
           County  Score  Score Pctl     Ozone
0          Fresno   89.0        97.0  0.065333
1  San Bernardino   89.0        97.0  0.055000
2       San Diego   86.0        95.0  0.053000
3   San Francisco   91.0        99.0  0.067000
```

You can also use other functions such as `max`, `min`, `std`, etc.:

```
>>> df.groupby('County', as_index=False).max()
           County  Score  Score Pctl  Ozone
0          Fresno     94         100  0.067
1  San Bernardino     89          97  0.055
2       San Diego     86          95  0.053
3   San Francisco     91          99  0.067

>>> df.groupby('County', as_index=False).min()
           County  Score  Score Pctl  Ozone
0          Fresno     86          95  0.064
1  San Bernardino     89          97  0.055
2       San Diego     86          95  0.053
3   San Francisco     91          99  0.067
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Still very new to this all, so this is my first time hearing about `.groupby`. Thank you for the explanation as well!